# X ∼ Bin(n, p) Probability mass function and Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim Bin\left(n,p\right) $ where $n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $p > 0$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]=2$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(X=0\right)=\frac{1}{27}$.

Define the probability mass function and cumulative distribution function of X.

All the examples I can find are more straightforward with known $n$ and $p$ values, how would one approach this problem?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: You have $E[X] =np$ and $P(X=0)=(1-p)^n$ so two simultaneous equations in two unknowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean of a Binomial distribution is already given as $np$. From the given probability,$$
P(X=0)=\binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^n=(1-p)^n=1/27
$$
So $$p=1-(1/27)^{1/n}$$
And$$E[X]=np=n(1-(1/27)^{1/n})=2$$
You can solve this for $n$ and substitute back for $p$. The pmf and CDF of a Binomial distribution can be found online and use your newlyfound $p$